# Including Tycho's itp02.bundle plugin in the itp04-rcp example.product

Tags: eclipse, maven, tycho, p2, osgi-bundle

I'm trying to figure out how the `pomfirst-thirdparty` bundle can be used within the `itp04-rcp` `eclipse-repository`.

I figure that I should be able to run:

```
> cd org.eclipse.tycho-demo\itp02\build02
> mvn org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:install
```

And then edit the `example.product` file in the `itp04-rcp\eclipse-repository` directory:

```
<plugins>
  <plugin id="tycho.demo.itp02.bundle" />
</plugins>
```

When I run `mvn package` in itp04-rc it complains:

```
Included element tycho.demo.itp02.bundle 0.0.0 is missing.
```

This works:

```
<plugins>
  <plugin id="example-bundle" version="0.0.0" />
</plugins>

<features>
  <!-- <feature id="example-feature" version="0.0.0"/> -->
  <feature id="org.eclipse.rcp" version="0.0.0"/>
  <feature id="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.user.ui" version="0.0.0"/>
</features>
```

**...so why not the itp02.bundle plugin?**

Comment: build02 is a Tycho build ("manifest first"). Why would you want to build it with the maven-bundle-plugin ("POM first")? Or did you mean to reference the build01 bundles?

Comment: Yes, I want to use the pom-first artifact in itp04 (I don't think it's actually used in any of the examples)

Comment: Could you reflect this in the question, i.e. edit the IDs so that they actually reference the POM first bundle from `itp02/build01`? The conflicting information makes it hard to be specific in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the `tycho.demo.itp02.bundle bundle` in a Tycho build if it is not in the [target platform](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Target_Platform) of the build.

Unlike for example a Maven dependency declaration, the dependency declaration in the product file, i.e. the `<plugin id="tycho.demo.itp02.bundle" />`,  is underspecified:

- It doens't specify a version.
- It doesn't specify in which p2 repository to look. (Unlike in Maven, there is no "central" p2 repository with all artifacts.)

To overcome this ambiguity and to pick specific artifact files in a deterministic way, a Tycho project needs a target platform with all candidate artifacts that may be used to match dependency declarations.

How to add content to the target platform depends on what kind of artifacts should be referenced (built by Tycho vs. not built by Tycho, locally built vs. consumed as binary, etc.). For the different options, see the target platform configuration: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Target_Platform

Comment: So do I add a regular maven dependency `<groupId>tycho.demo.itp02, <artifactId>pomfirst-thirdparty` to 
[itp04-rcp/eclipse-repository/pom.xml](http://git.eclipse.org/c/tycho/org.eclipse.tycho-demo.git/tree/itp04-rcp/eclipse-repository/pom.xml) and set `pomDependencies=consider` in [target-platform-configuration of the parent pom](http://git.eclipse.org/c/tycho/org.eclipse.tycho-demo.git/tree/itp04-rcp/pom.xml)?

Comment: Do the dependencies of `pomfirst-thirdparty` need to be deployed to Nexus as OSGI bundles, or can they be regular jars with standard maven-generated manifests?

Comment: @NicholasAlbion I can add POM snippets to the answer, but these would not match the original question. Please fix the question first so that it uses the right IDs.